# Response is coming but Request api call not triggered in network pannel with angular9

Tags: angular-material, angular9, mat-tab

Request api generated via promise or observable sometimes response is coming but request api call not triggered in chrome network pannel. reponse also getting wrong
example:
this.getTimeCollections().then(data=>{console.log(data)});

//in service.ts

getTimeCollections():Promise{

```
    const url = `${this.publicUrl}/time_collections`;

    return this.httpClient.get(url).toPromise();
```

}

here first time it returns correct data in response but if we call same function again it returns data where we checked console is printed but request not shown network pannel and response also not updated it returns previous data.
Here i used matTabmodule in this template if we remove matTab selector then it working fine.

Comment: Explain your situation better and provide some code

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the http observable for it execute:

```
const url = `${this.publicUrl}/time_collections`;
const response$ = this.httpClient.get(url);
response$.subscribe(response=>console.log(response));
```

Comment: not working request not triggered in network panel